# Can I decrease the audio latency of Android (for a Midi keyboard)?

Tags: audio

I've connected a MIDI keyboard to my Moto E4 and I'd like to decrease the audio latency.  I've searched online and found that Android OS doesn't do a great job processing audio signals quickly.  Is there something I can do about this?  This is a phone I don't use, so I'm open to anything - I've looked at options involving another OS (haven't found any), or rooting the OS and maybe something then.  I'd like to prioritize the audio signal as much as possible, I need to run one app and then output from the phone.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Android is not a Real-time-OS, and the selected device is AFAIR a low-end one. Therefore I would recommend first to disable all apps that are active by default and that are of no use to you. Especially some of the pre-installed Motorola apps. Alternatively a clean custom ROM may be an option. Anyway do you have a way to measure the audio latency or is everything up to your subjective recognition?

Comment: @Robert I'm going by ear.  Do you know a custom ROM that you would recommend for this?